# Image data URI failed to load with xmlhttp.responsetext

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a HTML file called storage.html, which has image data stored as a base64 encoded string  as:

```
<img class="bi x0 y0 w1 h1" alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABEoAAAWpCAIAAAD.....==">
```

and other divs too.

I get this stored data into another HTML file draw.html on load as:

```
function refresh_show_last_change()
        {
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                {
                    document.getElementById("page-container").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("POST", "storage.html", true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
```

page-container is a div to whom I want to give the contents of storage.html
I however get an error on this saying that the image (base64 encoded from storage.html failed to load)

The error is:

```
  Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_URL data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABEoAAAWpCAIAAADhg2AvAAAACXBIW…8AAADkDQAAgLwBAACQNwAAAPIGAAAAAADgr8p7AwAAjDhwFZJdGpWVPAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

Could someone let me know how can this be corrected. I want the divs and the base64 image src from storage .html to be extracted in xmlhttp.responsetext

Thanks in advance!

How I store the page-container innerhtml in storage.html as:

```
 function save() {
            // 1. Create XHR instance - Start
            var xhr;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            else {
                throw new Error("Ajax is not supported by this browser");
            }
            // 1. Create XHR instance - End


            var edited_data = document.getElementById("page-container").innerHTML;

            // 3. Specify your action, location and Send to the server - Start 
            xhr.open('POST', 'editor_change.php');
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xhr.send("edited_data=" + edited_data);
            // 3. Specify your action, location and Send to the server - End
        }
```

Comment: Try by replacing storage.html by storage.php with echo '<img src="base64stuff..." />'; in it. Does it work better that way?

Comment: It gives the same error

Comment: Are you sure you entered the correct path to your PHP script then? The file name must be a relative path to the PHP script, from the file containing the Ajax script. Maybe you have to do something like xmlhttp.open("POST", "../folder/storage.php", true); ?

Comment: Both the files are in the same folder.
What I do is save the page-container div's innerHTML into storage.html. then when I reload the page, the page-container div should display the contents stored in storage.html. On reloading is when it fails. The base64 string is created using the pdf2htmlEX.js and displays fine when created for the first time.

Comment: Also all other divs from storage.html are loaded correctly but only the base64 img src fails.

Comment: Ok, so, when you run the page for the first time, it works fine. Then the content is saved to storage.html. Then, on reloading it fails. Before reloading, you should try to run storage.html on its own, not by the Ajax script, and see what happens. Does the content displays correctly? If it does, then you have a problem with the Ajax script. If it doesn't, it may be the content which is the problem. Finally, you should check if the bas64 generation is working fine on its own too.

Comment: I think you are being really helpful :). So, the situation is, when I run storage.html on its own, it still gives the same error. So, the problem may be with the path, but then how does it run for the first time? How can I correct the error?

Comment: The base64 being stored in storage.html is different than the actual generated in the first time, this is causing the error. How may I be able to correct this?

Comment: How do you store the base64 in your html file? It certainly comes from there then ;)

Comment: I editted the question to let you know how I store the base64 data in storage.html, could you let me know if it needs any changes?

Comment: I thought about it for some time, I don't really get where there could be a problem... The only thing I can think of right now is maybe an encoding problem when saving the content is the html file by the Ajax request. I use Ajax a lot, and encoding issues are sadly very common.